# Android bundle: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, bundle, parcelable

I Am trying to send a `Parcelable` object from an `Activity` to a `IntentSerivce`. The code below was working well, I have made changes to the project but not that section, and have no idea why this has stopped working.

Activity:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("client", client);
bundle.putParcelable("job", job);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, EmailService.class);
intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
intent.putExtra("type", "type1");

startService(intent);
```

Service:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
  String type = intent.getStringExtra("type");

  Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle");
  Client client = bundle.getParcelable("client");
  ...
```

The line `Client client = bundle.getParcelable("client");` causes `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array`. The `Client` object is not null in the `Activity` and the `bundle` is not null in the `Service`. I am also able to pass my `Client` object around between activities without any problems.

Why has this stopped working / How do I fix this?

Comment: If Service is a `new Activity` then try to move everything that is inside `onHandleIntent` to `onCreate`, it feels that your onHandleIntent is getting called to quickly and the transition didn't happen yet

Comment: Why did you use `intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);`? you can use `intent.putExtra("client", client);
        intent.putExtra("job", job);` instead.

Comment: @Lamar Service runs in the background, I am trying to start it from an activity.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך is right

Comment: @ישו אוהב אותך I removed the bundle now the line: String type = intent.getStringExtra("type");  Is crashing.

Comment: That's strange. Could you add your `IntentService` code to your question?

Comment: OK, I figured it out. I had made changes to the job class, however I made a mistake with the parcelable implementation, which was messing up the entire bundle. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to put bundle. You can put your object or dto using intent . Then Parse this object in OnCreate of your activity. Thought you need to serialize your object or dto.

**Example:**

**Start activity Like this**

`Intent intent = new Intent(this, EmailService.class);
intent.putExtra("client", client);
intent.putExtra("job", job);`

**Then in Oncreate of you Activity parse like this**

```
Client client = (Client) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("client");
Job job = (Job) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("job");
```